# Pubsub signs the JWT token for push with a wrong key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jwt, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm using the following stack for my backend:

1. Cloud Endpoints
2. Cloud Run Gateway with ESPv2 => check API keys and validate JWTs
3. Cloud Run gRPC server implementation
4. When a change of interest happen I publish a message on pubsub

Now, attached to that pubsub topic I have a push subscription that triggers a Cloud Run method with a service account and a specified audience.

Setup:
[image]

Now I need to configure the Cloud Run Gateway to validate the JWT that pubsub generates for the specified service account. This is done in the `api_config.yaml` as per documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#jwt_format

The issuer is `https://accounts.google.com` and the audience in the one I specified in the pubsub subscription.

```yaml
authentication:
  providers:
    - id: gcloud
      jwks_uri: https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/875517523825-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
      issuer: https://accounts.google.com
      audiences: project.clounrun.admin
  rules:
    - selector: project.v2.Events.*
      requirements:
        - provider_id: gcloud
```

The jwks for this service account can be found here:
`https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/SERVICE-ACCOUNT-ID`

In my case:
`https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/875517523825-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/service-account-authentication#set_up_authentication_in_the_grpc_api_configuration

I've activated debug logs for the ESPv2 and this is what I get when it tries to validate the JWT:

```
13:07:37.027 request headers complete (end_stream=false):\n\':authority\', \'project-gateway-v2-dev-cuvfttrlpq-de.a.run.app\'\n\':path\', \'/v2/sessions:event\'\n\':method\', \'POST\'\n\'content-type\', \'application/json\'\n\'authorization\', \'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImQwNWVmMjBjNDUxOTFlZmY2NGIyNWQzODBkNDZmZGU1NWFjMjI5ZDEiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJ5aXRub3cuY2xvdW5ydW4uYWRtaW4iLCJhenAiOiIxMDk0NDIwMDAxNjU1ODQ3Nzc4MDciLCJlbWFpbCI6Ijg3NTUxNzUyMzgyNS1jb21wdXRlQGRldmVsb3Blci5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29tIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOnRydWUsImV4cCI6MTYwMzgwNzAwMSwiaWF0IjoxNjAzODAzNDAxLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FjY291bnRzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20iLCJzdWIiOiIxMDk0NDIwMDAxNjU1ODQ3Nzc4MDcifQ.PwLvaBz-_dM3_5VjgzVlaueoRhacUE39FdFuVSfQI2w4V3OD79tIA6t_0cuvE1-kIpNrfDda5RSavVcs4SV4Y5P8AvW5jDtHdCELP3yb8HzVT9nCJlLac-v5ZKuv06syBN9F2Ve7VtZHHZOE2VS4B7uw0Q__1rIVzIllYWBYHkYGUBP2mZ3VhRw9VXARMr-EICanXfETe_MMfoKsX4202L_O4LffPdv16pA5hYtwzKi67gFYuubKI1XNkVQVatQieYQrhkz5jMyNyhVKy8ZY5a2UXagQL7erdsm-uPJo6ujoq0Yxtl8iKMdRv4XfrQSLyFZHCYdO6n2LHJle_FQzCQ\'\n\'content-length\', \'335\'\n\'accept\', \'application/json\'\n\'from\', \'noreply@google.com\'\n\'user-agent\', \'APIs-Google; (+https://developers.google.com/webmasters/APIs-Google.html)\'\n\'x-cloud-trace-context\', \'c3027b54c6aad09d85ce75f6dcaf07d5/8778433264575104852\'\n\'x-forwarded-for\', \'66.249.82.169\'\n\'x-forwarded-proto\', \'https\'\n\'forwarded\', \'for=\"66.249.82.169\";proto=https\'\n\'accept-encoding\', \'gzip,deflate,br\'
13:07:37.027 Called Filter : setDecoderFilterCallbacks
13:07:37.027 matched operation: project.v2.Events.OnSessionEvent
13:07:37.027 Called Filter : decodeHeaders
13:07:37.027 use filter state value project.v2.Events.OnSessionEvent to find verifier.
13:07:37.028 extract authorizationBearer
13:07:37.028 extract x-goog-iap-jwt-assertion
13:07:37.028 gcloud: JWT authentication starts (allow_failed=false), tokens size=1
13:07:37.028 gcloud: startVerify: tokens size 1
13:07:37.028 gcloud: Verifying JWT token of issuer https://accounts.google.com
13:07:37.028 gcloud: JWT token verification completed with: Jwks doesn\'t have key to match kid or alg from Jwt
13:07:37.028 Called Filter : check complete Jwks doesn\'t have key to match kid or alg from Jwt
13:07:37.028 Sending local reply with details jwt_authn_access_denied
```

As you can see the jwks doesn't contain the JWT kid. And this is true.

The header of this JWT is this:

```json
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "d05ef20c45191eff64b25d380d46fde55ac229d1",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

and the payload is this:

```json
{
  "aud": "project.clounrun.admin",
  "azp": "109442000165584777807",
  "email": "875517523825-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "exp": 1603807001,
  "iat": 1603803401,
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "sub": "109442000165584777807"
}
```

This indicates that pubsub does indeed use that service account but it looks like that specific kid is missing from the jwks response.

```json
{
  "4366ae10d4a79728de14f6f89a628b4fe640140f": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
  "e0b3368c1646eb88d93b9d0b2d65e2d6fbae27b7": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nRXHDLiUfU0A=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
  "c0191d2d00f89eb1905886a04335a79a124885e1": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIDNDCCAhygAwIBAgIIaTwbvrNhTkYwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwPTE7MDkGA1UE\nAxMyODc1NTE3NTIzODI1LWNvbXB1dGUuZGV2ZWxvcGVyLmdzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3Vu\ndC5jb20wHhcNMjAxMDI4MDA0NDEwWhcNMjAxMTEzMTI1OTEwWjA9MTswOQYDVQQD\nEzI4NzU1MTc1MjM4MjUtY29tcHV0ZS5kZXZlbG9wZXIuZ3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50\nLmNvbTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAKJZDpcJAHyot7z9\n0EAOOEC6+dwlkxduThH5FQXlaCUoHRAoCtTHrxeITSsZg55cXGXKzTTf1Nv+UE9E\nTY5nhU70nEK77B5FbxwzX9Q/OkOhP3NQnl0U0O6nedfCJvOtCMdopHnrRa+ZIWhG\nPoW2RKQTv7gr4bGFJnQshcYDtrahH6Xv/RfyyTnI9AUzCX6eVO3g7odLSdcv+qnV\niqsZLCqz2lflKky+Rti/1f8LGXySTs+r7bdvqCdpbIm6f79WqQ720hmx+4JaIuS3\nYmYztK5J6JwsDLqULyyMvZs9vVA6cK1+580Vb76pkF9MHqTZdZ2gPP1qoKCO0ezI\nK3lYfGECAwEAAaM4MDYwDAYDVR0TAQH/BAIwADAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCB4AwFgYD\nVR0lAQH/BAwwCgYIKwYBBQUHAwIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAHB+6GiylFKU\nq9nyzrvlTRe0tph7kT6D8WhlnxGDgnDOn9xAB360xh+KPczq7+8DJczSb5145No/\nefrCUpvgkraVe/eTsu8EAjDjk/XPOeV4117EU+PRVV5nitYiVGJ0Z+3V3kHCnqLT\ntTxQlKDRpJ02GjhQRkW03fhLEFr7eu79fiwfjfaFSoAAIrNxBi3mtrhcidu43zD1\n/VXAReH26S129UoYz7fPlsnULX/oUyZPidaKIZ2Fl5N2QTgXnd1PnU3HgesU4HWs\nYJeiq6Z1pFxTw9192VD3MgDSDVQAeHXs+wTQsUHftMcNl7nPWl9YfiPjzD4sNWL3\n8whVkhIN8r4=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
}
```

We have:

- `4366ae10d4a79728de14f6f89a628b4fe640140f`
- `e0b3368c1646eb88d93b9d0b2d65e2d6fbae27b7`
- `c0191d2d00f89eb1905886a04335a79a124885e1`

But no

- `d05ef20c45191eff64b25d380d46fde55ac229d1`

If pubsub is using a different key that where can I find the jwks?

UPDATE:
I verified all my services accounts JWKS links and none of them contain that kid. So this is very strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a Google signing key (Google is signing for you).

This means you need to lookup the KID from Google's published public keys.

You will find the public certificate kid here: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs

For some added context, each service account has a sort of "hidden` key. Google manages and controls this key. When you request an Identity Token from Google, the JWT is signed using this special key. That is why you need to look this up in Google's public certificate list instead of your service account's certificate list.